# how to create single common class for jdbc connection pool

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling

I am using jdbc connection pooling and i am getting the connection more than 100 place in the web application. how can i write the common code in single class and call, where required.

```
 Context initContext = new InitialContext();
 Context envContext = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
 DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/UserDB");
 Connection con = ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: Are you using a dependency injection framework like Spring?

Comment: Take a look at Spring JDBCTemplate, which is thread-safe (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate-idioms).

Comment: @JoseMartinez  i m using only jsp and servlet